# Quotes in command line arguments passed to Java main()

Tags: java, netbeans, escaping, quotes

I run a Java program with the following command line (Edit: in NetBeans 6.8 project properties)

```
toto has:"tutu titi"
```

args is an array of 2 Strings

```
toto
has:tutu titi
```

I want (two arguments indeed, the second) `args[1]` to be

```
has:"tutu titi"
```

How should I do that?

Edit: I have already tried escaping the quotes with backslash from "Arguments" line in Netbeans propject properties, but I get args[1]

```
has:\tutu titi\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem in NetBeans and found the solution:

Edit/Add the property "application.args" in your private.properties to this:

```
application.args='has:""tutu titi""'
```

Single quotes to mark your "argument" and two double quotes to define one "double quotes".

Answer (score 9):

This really depends on your shell. You haven't said what operating system you're using. For example, on Windows this will work:

```
java Test toto "has:\"tutu titi\""
```

I believe the same thing will work in bash, too.

But if you're asking what you can do *within Java* to resolve this: nothing. The shell will have parsed the command line before the process was invoked, and you can't undo that parsing.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
toto "has:\"tutu titi\""
```

Comment: In a shell, has:"tutu titi" is already considered as a single argument. There is no need to add extra quotes around.

Comment: @rds: There is when you've escaped the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This has been recognised by netbeans as [a bug that won't be fixed](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191254)!

Comment: Would you perhaps have any links that could substantiate that fact? If you could add those to your answer it would make it more relevant.

Comment: i think this is the link [link]https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191254

Answer (score 1):

If adding from NetBeans (7.1.2) Configuration/Arguments dialog field, a single-quote outer and escaped double quote inner worked for me e.g.:

```
my argument
```