# Argument sent to jar (started programmatically) has all double-quotes removed

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I have a small console SpringBoot app which receives arguments via command line. When I run this app in command line as `java -jar` everything works fine. The problem is that I need to run this app programmatically from the other java app. I do it like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
                "java",
                "-jar",
                pathToJar,
                "--text",
                payload
        });
```

Where `payload` is a json, smth like:

```
String payload= "{\"app\":{\"name\":\"SOME_NAME\",\"signature\":\"308203a73092a86\"}}
```

For some mysterious reason the payload text comes without any double-quotes. I logged it in that SprintBoot app as the very first command like this:

```
public static void main(final @Nonnull String... args) {
    for(String arg: args){
        LOG.info(arg);
    }
```

and I can see that it comes without any double-quotes! Logged values look like this:

```
2020-09-28 15:31:56.565 | INF | .t.s.a.AttestationTool | --text
2020-09-28 15:31:56.565 | INF | .t.s.a.AttestationTool | {app:{name:SOME_NAME,signature:308203a73092a86}}
2020-09-28 15:31:56.565 | INF | .t.s.a.AttestationTool | Starting application
```

If use single quotes they get passed to the application. Unfortunately I have to use double-quotes only. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Can you share the log you're printing out, just to make it clearer?

Comment: Hi @Mureinik. I have added an example of logged values

Comment: Is this windows?  this seems to be a known "bug" on windows: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6468220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

[This depends on the shell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3960200/9619325.). if you pass String as follows this should works: (worked on Windows CMD and git bash)

```
{"""app""":{"""name""":"""SOME_NAME""","""signature""":"""308203a73092a86"""}}"
```

you can use replaceAll method to replace each double quote with 3 double quotes:

```
String payload= "{\"app\":{\"name\":\"SOME_NAME\",\"signature\":\"308203a73092a86\"}}"
payload = payload.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"\"");
```

Comment: runtime exec does not use a shell.

Comment: This answer point to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3960200/9619325. Is it wrong?

Comment: yw. if this is your question's answer, please accept the answer.